# issue still ask credentiels with rsync over ssh with sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo, rsync

I want to sync 2 servers with rsync. Os are Ubuntu 16.04
I'm using a user named here `syncuser`
user is in `sudo` group, on both servers

in `/etc/sudoers` I put (on both servers)

```
syncuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync
```

Then from local

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (remote server)
```

I can check ssh connection without credentials working
I can check sudo rsync without credentials on both
So now I run from local

```
sudo rsync -avz -e "ssh" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" /home/data/ syncuser@remoteserver:/home/data/
```

and.... 
now prompt password for syncuser@remoteserver !

I don't think I forgot something

Answer (score 1):

You are running:

```
sudo rsync -e "ssh"
```

You  execute `ssh` from `root` account (as you used `sudo` before running the `rsync` command) instead of `syncuser` account (which have `ssh` access to the remote-server)

In order to solve it, you can allow `root@local-host` access to `syncuser@remote-host` (e.g. using `ssh-copy-id`)?

Comment: You win ! Of course I had to copy root :

Comment: @FabriceGossart - If I've answered your question please [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) it